# fill <li> background using href link inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply a class to the `<li>` but i do not seem to find any way to do it.

here is my html.

**html markup:**

```
<nav class="topNav">
     <ul>
          <li id="bannera" onclick="clickOnli(href='#banner')">
                <a href="#banner">Notify<img src="images/news-feed.png" class="topNavImages navNewsPic"></a>
          </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var aChildren = $("nav li").children();
        var aArray = [];
        for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++)
        {    
            var aChild = aChildren[i];
            var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
            aArray.push(ahref);
        }

        $(window).scroll(function()
        {
            var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/1.5;
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var docHeight = $(document).height();

            for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++)
            {
                var theID = aArray[i];
                var divPos = $(theID).offset().top;
                var divHeight = $(theID).height();

                if (windowPos >= divPos)
                {
                    $('a').removeClass("fillBlue");
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("fillBlue");
                }
            }

            if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight)
            {
                if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("fillBlue"))
                {
                    var navActiveCurrent = $(".fillBlue").attr("href");
                    $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("fillBlue");
                    $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("fillBlue");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to fill the li background not `<a>`link/tag background. How do i change this `$("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("fillBlue");` so that i can fill this ID's li background.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("fillBlue");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("fillBlue");
```

Comment: you as Jack posted the same, it worked. When my time limit ends I will accept your answer.